# Can simple risk management outperform portfolio optimization like this, or is there most likely an error?

Tags: volatility, portfolio-optimization, markowitz, portfolio-selection, diversification

I am using a simulation approach to compare the performances achievable by simple risk management and portfolio optimization for portfolio selection. My problem is that my results indicate that simple risk management outperforms portfolio optimization. Is this possible or is there most likely an error in my simulation?

My simulation approach is as follows. Assume there are N different assets in the universe, each of which is assigned to one of K groups, based on some properties. For each of these assets I have daily returns data for a two-year period. Each iteration in the simulation **randomly** selects one asset from each of the groups. I.e., K assets are selected and will be assigned a weight in $[0, 1]$ Then, each asset is assigned a weight. The mean-variance approach calculates the optimal weights based on the daily returns data. The naive approach simply assigns the weight $1/M$ to each of the assets in the portfolio. This gives the portfolio returns, from which I calculate annualized portfolio volatility. The results are shown in the table below. Could these results be feasible or could it be that I made a mistake somewhere (e.g., mixed up the column names, incorrectly multiplied returns with weights, etc.)?

Edit: the optimal portfolio is the one with minimal variance over all returns.

Comment: What is your optimal portfolio, exactly? Is it supposed to be the minimal variance portfolio over all possible returns? If so, the only explanation left besides an error is estimation error. Your naive method doesn't require any estimation, but a mean-variance optimization requires a covariance matrix which can be poorly estimated... With K assets, you're talking about K first moments plus K(K+1)/2 second moments, so it can quickly be A LOT to demand from data. But, then again, I have no idea what you're doing in your simulation.

Comment: yes, I use  the minimal variance portfolio over all possible returns as the optimal portfolio

Comment: Are you comparing the sample in-sample or out-of-sample? In-sample it might be due to the estimation errors, out-of-sample i would bet Naive diversification would beat mean-variance most of the times, refer to this study https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2713501

Comment: Year 1 is in-sample, while year 2 is out-of-sample.

Comment: Are the vols in the table in %? It looks a bit suspicious that out-of-sample vols are larger than in-sample vols. What is the size of N and K in your simulation?

Comment: @Pontus Hultkrantz: the vols. in year 1 are larger because that particular market was a lot more volatile that year, if I understood your question correctly. N is 100 and K varies between 5 and 19.

Comment: @AliMustafa: yes my bad. Unfortunately, it is difficult to know if there is a mistake unless you show us more in detail (mathematically) how you did it. How do you calculate the covariance/correlation, using all data in year 1, or calculating a running covariance? E.g on day 10, you have 10 samples, on day 250 you have a full year of samples.

Comment: @AliMustafa: I recommend that you pick a covariance matrix as the truth (e.g. from estimating the market prices), simulate (monte carlo) e.g. normal returns from this covariance matrix, and do the mean variance calculation on these returns.

Comment: @Pontus Hultkrantz: thanks, I might try that. Do you think my results would make more sense if the headers were switched so that mean-variance would produce the lowest volatilities?

Comment: Please note that self destruction of content is not allowed.

Comment: what do you mean? Is it illegal to delete a question? Then why is there delete button?

Comment: It's not illegal, it's against the TOS. It would be nice if you our @PontusHultkrantz can summarize the comments into an answer.